# Windows takes a very long time to shut down even in safe mode

Tags: windows-7

On Windows 7 the computer freezes for about 5 minutes once it gets to "Shutting down...". I can't remember when it started happening. I just lived with it for a while.

The first thing I tried was a full scan using Microsoft Security Essentials. This did not solve the problem.

I then went into msconfig and turned off everything I could get away with in the startup and services tabs. This did not solve the problem.

I then uninstalled every program on this computer save the most basic programs. This did not solve the problem (did not uninstall drivers or catalyst).

I then went through and turned off every single service and did a reboot. This did not solve the problem.

I then booted into safe mode and just tried shutting it down. The problem even happens in safe mode.

I have tried examining the event logs but with no success. They just say things like "blah blah has entered the stopped state" with no real clues about what program is causing me all this grief.

*it may be worth noting that Ubuntu is installed on the same computer and the ubuntu boot loader is the one being used.

Comment: it could be a deamon process not shutting down when asked to

Comment: is there any way to figure out which one? if i knew which one i would just nuke the entire app

Comment: Have you tried a system restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed up a friends computer with similar symptoms - the cause turned out to be a rootkit that was booting from a 20MB hidden partition carved off the end of the drive.

The rootkit was getting control when the machine booted, and was in turn booting the legitimate OS and hosting it. Long shutdown times for the machine were a result of the malware allowing it's processes to finish before continuing the shutdown.

Ended up nuking the whole drive - including the partition table, and starting from scratch with a fresh OS install.

Would be worth checking the partitions on your drive to make sure that only the legit ones are there.

One note: In my case the malware partition was marked as hidden and didn't show up in most partition tools; I stumbled across it when using a Linux live-cd to do a malware scan.

PS: I really hope this **is not** the solution to your problem, as removing this kind of malware is tedious and nasty.

Comment: probably was a mbr rootkit, nasty devils.

Comment: in order to avoid debugging pains i just did a reinstall. also helped me fix my soundcard in the process so all is good. reinstall only took 20 minutes plus another ten to install every web browser, security essentials, inkscape, gimp, and a few utilities. ...visual studio will be a pain though.

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc752957.aspx) allows you to trace Shutdown and determine the cause of a slow shutdown.

[Windows On/Off Transition Performance Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463386) describes how this is done.

There is a [useful introduction](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140247-trace-windows-7-bootshutdownhibernatestandbyresume-issues/) on the MSFN website.